# Eclipse not able to display logs properly in jelly bean

Tags: android, eclipse, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I just installed jelly bean in my galaxy nexus phone and trying to debug my app. After connecting to my pc, i noticed that Eclipse is not able to read the log info properly in the logcat. The text column is displayed properly but i see a ? mark in other columns like tag, PID, etc.

Comment: Just a long-shot but are you using the latest eclipse, ADT and android sdk etc?

Comment: I've got 4.1.1 and everything is fine.

Comment: not sure about the latest ADT/SDK .. i'll neway try to update n check if that helps

Comment: @Squonk yes, perfect! i hadn't updated my eclipse and the ADT since long. did it now and the logs are back! along with, im sure, few other things solved too. Thanks :)

Comment: @RahulDole : Good news, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a case of outdated ADT tool

Comment: @silverback yes thats true. I have already commented above about it.

Comment: sorry, didn't read through the comments, i was searching for something else when i came across this in a related query.